# How to add a constraint on a table in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

So I have an account table, employee table and a customer table. How to set a constraint on account table so an employee cannot be a customer at the same branch where he/she works.

**Code for Account table**

```
create type account_type as object(
accNum number,
accType varchar2(15),
balance number, 
bID ref branch_type,
inRate number,
limitOfFreeOD number,
custID ref customer_type,
openDate DATE)
/
create table account_table of account_type(
primary key (accNum))
/
```

**Code for employee table**

```
create type employee_type as object(
empID integer,
eName EmployeeName,
eAddress EmployeeAddress,
eContact EmployeeContact,
phone tp_phone_array,
supervisorID ref employee_type,
eDetails EmployeeWorkDetails,
bID ref branch_type,
joinDate Date);
/
create table employee_table of employee_type(
primary key (empID))
/
```

**Code for customer table**

```
create type customer_type as object(
custID number,
cName customerName,
cAddress customerAddress,
cHomeContact custhomeContact,
cMobile tp_mobile_array,
cTaxDetails custTaxDetails)
/

create table customer of customer_type(
primary key (custID))
/
```

At the moment I am adding normal customer data like this in account table:

```
insert into account_table
select account_type('1520','current','4154.20',ref(b),'0.090','200',ref(c),'20-Aug-16')
from branch b
where b.bID = '500'
and c.custID = '301';
/
```

**These are table attributes:**

Account(accNum, accType, balance, bID, inRate, limitOfFreeOD, openDate)

Employee(empID, street, city, postCode, title, firstName, surName, empHomePhone,
empMobile1, empMobile2, supervisorID, position, salary, niNum, bID, joinDate)

Customer(custID, street, city, postCode, title, firstName, surName, custHomePhone,
custMobile1, custMobile2, niNum)

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using "object-relational"?  It is insane...

Comment: Is it okay now?

Comment: I meant: why are you **using** object-relational techniques, creating tables based on object types?  Nobody does that in the real world (I would hope).

Comment: I am doing practice from oracle docs, that's why I used like that. Completely a newbie.

Comment: OK, have fun!  Sorry but I don't know the answer to your question.